# CopyTo Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to get this code to work but keep getting a "TypeError: offset.copyTo is not a function". The script is supposed to take one value from sheet "Budget" and copy it into the next available row in column F on sheet "Projected".

I have tried playing around with syntax and other ways to copy but to now avail, any help would be greatly appreciated

```js
function OffsetRecord() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xx").getSheetByName("Budget");
 var offset = sheet.getRange('I5').getValue();
 var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xx").getSheetByName("Projected");
 var colF = destSheet.getRange('F:F').getValues();
 var fcolF = colF.filter(function (e) {return e[0];});
 var firstEmptyRowIncolF = fcolF.indexOf('')+1;
 offset.copyTo(firstEmptyRowIncolF, {contentsOnly: true});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `copyTo` expects ranges as parameters, not values or column numbers, see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)

Modify your code as following:

```
function OffsetRecord() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XX");
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Budget");
  var offset = sheet.getRange('I5');//without ".getValue();"!
  var destSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Projected");
  ...
  firstEmptyRowIncolF = ...;
  var destinationColumn = 1;
  var range = destSheet.getRange(firstEmptyRowIncolF, destinationColumn);
  offset.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried this after adding the original "firstEmptyRowIncolF =.." variables...now I am getting  "Exception: The starting row of the range is too small.". Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I intentionally replaced your query for theempty row by `...` since this is not the way I would retrieve it. I would get the first empty row with `var firstEmptyRowIncolF = (destSheet.getLastRow()+1);`. See [here](https://develope.rs.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to work out how to get it to copy to the next non-empty row in Column F, getlastrow() points to the very end of the spreadsheet

Comment: Use [getNextDataCell(direction)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnextdatacelldirection). For example `(destSheet.getRange("F1").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow()+1)`

Comment: Sidenote: If you want to copy the data specifically to the first free row, it might make sense for you to use the method [sheet.appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents) instead of `copyTo`.